# primefaces 3.5 calendar hour minute pattern javascript error

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, calendar

I'm using `PF3.5` and when I use a calendar component with a pattern including HH:mm I get the following javascript error and the caalendar selctor icon is'nt shown:
Uncaught Unexpected literal at position 2

This is de jsf code:

```
<p:calendar value="#{incidentDetail.incidentDateTime}" id="incident_date" locale="#{ws.locale}" showOn="button" yearRange="-2:+1" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" navigator="true" mindate="1900-01-01" required="true" styleClass="required calmedium"/>
```

When I use `pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"` it works

Any solution on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the same pattern to mindate

```
mindate="01/01/1900"
```